# What's the exact meaning of "mud-flinging"?

Tags: word-meaning, expressions

I came across the word "mud-flinging" in a news title this morning,

> G.O.P. Presidential Hopefuls Gird for a Month of **Mud-Flinging**.

It infers a meaning of scolding or attacking each other, but it is not included in my dictionaries. What's the exact meaning of "mud-flinging"?

Comment: A correction: it **implies** that meaning.  *You* **infer** that meaning.  [This  is something many native English speakers get wrong, though!](http://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/imply-infer/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about etymology, which is suitable for [English.SE].

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think it's mostly about meaning and only a little about origin, so I think we can leave it open and ignore the etymology part. Simply editing out "and origin" would make it on-topic.

Comment: See Tfd idioms to throw mud at sb. Instead of "throw" you can find some variants such as to sling or to fling. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+mud+at

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Fling* means "throw", usually with a sense of violence; *mud* is wet dirt, which sticks and soils when it hits somebody you throw it at. Politicians fling figurative mud, charges of improper behavior or opinions, at a rival in the hope that the mud will 'stick'—that the public will believe the charges and recoil from voting for the rival.

*Mud**sling**ing* means exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> MUDSLINGING
>
> noun
>
> 1.the use of insults and accusations, especially unjust ones, with the aim of damaging the reputation of an opponent.

Often, when a word is used incorrectly enough times, by enough people, it ends up becoming an accepted synonym *for* the correct word. "Mud-flinging" is one of *those* words.

Comment: In what way is *mudslinging* used incorrectly? And what is the "correct" word?

Comment: "Mud-flinging" being used when *Mudslinging* is meant.

Comment: Both have been in use since the early 19th century, and I see no reason why one should be preferred to the other.

Comment: Dost thou flingeth thine besmirched water at me, good sir? (Methinks we sounded odd, then.) [joking w/ you btw]

Comment: @StoneyB The linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mud+slinging%2Cmud+flinging&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmud%20slinging%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmud%20flinging%3B%2Cc0) shows a big difference.

Comment: @Rathony Try [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(mud+slinging)%2B(mud-slinging)%2Bmudslinging%2C(mud+flinging)%2B(mud-flinging)%2Bmudflinging&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28%28mud%20slinging%29%20%2B%20%28mud%20-%20slinging%29%20%2B%20mudslinging%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28mud%20flinging%29%20%2B%20%28mud%20-%20flinging%29%20%2B%20mudflinging%29%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me that I had never seen "mud-flinging" and came to check it online. It seems I'm not alone. The usual expression is 'mudslinging".
 So the writer might have "misremembered" the expression or simply wanted to coin a novel phrase.